# Row names to column and modify dates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, statistics, modifier

how can i modify the names to date format and put them in a column as dates?

```
names(df)     
      [6] "X1.23.20"       "X1.24.20"       "X1.25.20"       "X1.26.20"       "X1.27.20"      
     [11] "X1.28.20"       "X1.29.20"       "X1.30.20"       "X1.31.20"       "X02.01.2020"   
     [16] "X02.02.2020"    "X02.03.2020"    "X02.04.2020"    "X02.05.2020"    "X02.06.2020"   
     [21] "X02.07.2020"    "X02.08.2020"    "X02.09.2020"    "X02.10.2020"    "X02.11.2020"   
     [26] "X02.12.2020"    "X2.13.20"       "X2.14.20"       "X2.15.20"       "X2.16.20"      
     [31] "X2.17.20"       "X2.18.20"       "X2.19.20"       "X2.20.20"       "X2.21.20"      
     [36] "X2.22.20"       "X2.23.20"       "X2.24.20"       "X2.25.20"       "X2.26.20"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as.Date` with specified format, e.g.,

```
> as.Date(v,"X%m.%d.%y")
[1] "2020-01-23" "2020-01-24" "2020-02-02" "2020-02-03"
```

**data**

```
v <- c("X1.23.20","X1.24.20","X02.02.2020","X02.03.2020")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `mdy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
mdy(sub("^X", "", names(df)))
```

Using a reproducible example

```
v1 <- c("X1.23.20" , "X02.04.2020"  )
mdy(sub("^X", "", v1))
#[1] "2020-01-23" "2020-02-04"
```